# Scope of class declaration

Tags: php, class, scope, declaration

I have a file `classes.php` in which I declare a set of classes to be used in a series of pages.
Then, in one page, I need to use another class, that is declared in a separate file. Now, this separate class uses some classes located in the `classes.php` file.

So, in most pages, I have:

```
[1]
<?php
require('classes.php');
[page code]
?>
```

which works fine. The problem comes with that specific page, which has:

```
[2]
<?php
require('classes.php');
require('separate_class.php');
[page code]
?>
```

and this does not work because `separate_class.php` also requires `classes.php`.

If I try this:

```
[3]
<?php
require('separate_class.php');
[page code]
?>
```

then it does not work because now the classes are not available for this page, even if they are declared inside the `separate_class.php` file.

The obvious solution seems to be the inclusion of the separate class in the `classes.php` file, which is clumsy because this separate class makes sense only in this series of pages, while the file `classes.php` contains general purpose classes and is shared among various applications.

How can I do it in a way that allows me to keep a structure like shown in [2], that is, separating general-purpose classes from a specific class which, in turn, requires those general-purpose classes, while still being able to use these general-purpose classes in the page?

Answer (score 6):

A more sound solution may be to seperate each class into it's own file and use an autoloader...

http://php.net/manual/en/function.spl-autoload.php

Comment: Already tried, gives me an error about class already declared.
That is what is making me crazy, the classes are present if I try to declare them again, but NOT if I try to use them.

Answer (score 5):

You want to use [require_once](http://php.net/manual/en/function.require-once.php)()

*EDIT:* You can't redeclare a class if that's what you are trying to do. I don't know what your code looks like, but maybe [inheritance](http://www.webreference.com/programming/php/class_inherit/) is what you are looking for??

*EDIT 2:* I have only been able to reproduce your error when I had a `require 'classes.php'` in separate_class.php AND a require 'classes.php' in the script you are actually opening. So you have 2 options:

- Don't `require` (or `require_once`) classes.php in your script before you have required separate_class.php
- Use require_once *everywhere* (check separate_class.php) and don't worry about whether or not a file has been required.

Comment: Actually require_once() is what I am using. But I already tried all four possibilities: require(), require_once(), include(), and include_once(). It seems to make no difference.

Comment: @Panglossa: It should work unless you have something weird going on in classes.php or separate_class.php.  Do you have a circular dependency?

Comment: @Panglossa You can't redeclare a class if that's what you are trying to do.

Comment: In the problematic file I have this:

require_once('classes.php'); //this contains the base classes
require_once('separate_class.php'); //this contains a special class used only in this page

The issue is: how can I use the classes from 'classes.php' both in this page and in the 'separate_class.php' file. If I do like above, I get a re-declaration error. Without including the 'classes.php' file inside 'separate_class.php' or inside the page, I get a class not found error.